# How to improve search results filtering on taxonomy

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, search

I would like to know the best way to filter drupal search results using taxonomy. I want users to be able to search for particular results from a particular taxonomy..this can be done to refine already searched results, or can be done from scratch.

Any module for Drupal 7 that does this well?

Comment: why dont u use views with expose filters

Answer (score 0):

Use [Custom Search](http://drupal.org/project/custom_search) module.

> This module alters the default search box in many ways. If you need to
>   have options available like in advanced search, but directly in the
>   search box

Or, the other best solution is to use create a view with exposed filters. Here is [article](http://s1l.org/views-3-exposed-filters-block) about it

Comment: Thanks for the article, I tried custom search but it didn't quite get there :'(

Answer (score 0):

I  think you should give a try to [Extending Drupal 7 search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8575289/extending-drupal-7-search). The form ID on the search result page would be `search_form`. You can use [hook_search_execute()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search.api.php/function/hook_search_execute/7) to filter the result as you need.

Or you could also try the [Extended search page](http://drupal.org/project/ext_search_page) module, but it is in beta and it requires [Search API](http://drupal.org/project/search_api) and [Search API pages](http://drupal.org/project/search_api_page).

Personally I would write a custom module rather than installing many modules.

Answer (score 0):

One of the best solution to this is using [Faceted search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faceted_search). You need to switch search engine to Solr to get that. There are several different vendors that sell Solr hosting if you don't want to set that up yourself, including Acquia.

Drupal integration is provided either by [Apache Solr search integration](http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr) or [Search API](http://drupal.org/project/search_api).